# The Hat matrix in the weighted least square

Tags: regression, linear-model, weighted-regression

From the ordinary least squares (OLS) problem, given a design matrix $X_{n\times p}$ and a response $y_{n \times 1}$, we want to find
$$
\hat\theta = \arg\min_\theta \|X\theta-y\|^2.
$$
In this case, the hat matrix is defined as $H = X (X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top$ such that the predicted response is given by $\hat{y} = H y$.

Now, consider the weighted least square (WLS), where for each data $i$, we assign a non-negative weight $w_i$ to which such that we want to find
$$
 \hat{\theta}
 = \arg\min_{\theta } \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i \left\vert x_i ^{\top} \theta - y_i \right\vert
 = \arg\min_{\theta } \lVert W^{1 / 2} (X \theta - y)\rVert ^2_2,
$$
where $W = \mathrm{diag}(w_1, \dots, w_n)$. To define the hat matrix:

1. From the definition of the hat matrix, we essentially want a $H$ such that the predicted response $\hat{y}$ is $H y$. In the case of WLS, it's $H = X (X^\top W X) ^{-1} X^{\top} W$.
2. However, observe that by considering $X' = W^{1/2}X$ and $y'=W^{1/2}y$, WLS falls back to OLS with new data $X'$ and $y'$. In this case,
   $$
   H' 
   = (W^{1/2}X) \cdot \left[(W^{1/2}X)^\top (W^{1/2}X)\right]^{-1} (W^{1/2}X)^\top
   = W^{1/2} X (X^\top W X)^{-1} X^\top W^{1/2}.
   $$

It's clear that $H \neq H'$, but I can't figure out where the discrepancy comes from.

Note that according to various sources (e.g., [Wikipidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares), other [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376902/how-to-compute-the-hat-matrix-of-constrained-least-squares)), the first definition should be used.

Edit: In the modified OLS case, the predicted response is
$$
\hat{y}' = H' y' = W^{1/2} X(X^\top W X)^{-1} X^\top W^{1/2} \cdot W^{1/2} y = W^{1/2} Hy = W^{1/2} \hat{y},
$$
which is what we expect. So I guess it's safe to assume that when considering modified OLS for WLS, $H'$ is the right choice? In other words, the hat matrix defined for different formulations is naturally different?

Comment: Hint: what quantity must $H^\prime$ multiply to produce the predicted value?

Comment: @whuber I have edited my post.

Comment: You didn't need to modify it: my hint concerned the answer to your question.