The Hat Matrix in Logistic Regression
I am trying to understand the hat matrix in logistic regression.
In linear regression, we have that $\hat{\beta}(y)=(X^TX)^{−1}X^Ty$ and we know that $$X\hat{\beta}(y)=X(X^TX)^{−1}X^Ty$$ which gives us the predicted values $\hat{y}$. Here, we can consider the matrix product $$X(X^TX)^{−1}X^T$$ as a single matrix that transforms an observation y such that $Hy=\hat{y}$
In logistic regression, the estimated $\beta$ through the Newton-Raphson method is given by $$\beta_{t+1} = \beta_t + X(Y-\hat{Y}_t)(X^T W_t X)^{-1}.$$
I have found that the hat matrix looks like this:
$$H = W^{1/2} X (X^T W X)^{-1} X^T W^{1/2}$$
I would like to know how this hat matrix is derived in logistic regression and how it relates to the $X\hat{\beta}$ as in linear regression.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376902/how-to-compute-the-hat-matrix-of-constrained-least-squares for a derivation and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629620/the-hat-matrix-in-the-weighted-least-square for what appears to be the same as your question.  //  Logistic regression does not have a hat matrix, though: this is a hat matrix for a weighted least squares regression that is iterated at each step to approach a solution to the logistic regression.
